# Google Cloud Platform - Billing, how do I find the name of the instance of a product that is costing money?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I go into billing and filter by project & group by SKU.  This gives me the individual services that I'm being charged for (view below).  I can see that Compute Engine is costing me £5.59 per month.  If I go into Compute Engine I don't have any instances.  In this particular example I discovered that had a Serverless VPC Connector running and I think that is using the Service but it is just a guess.

How do I find out what specific product instances that I have enabled are costing me money?  How, in this example, would I find out from Billing that it is the Serverless VPC Connector that is costing me money and linked to that Compute Engine instance?

(I've had other situations where I'm being billed for an IP address but not the name of that IP address or what products / instances of products are consuming the IP address).

[image]

Comment: @YevGuyduy unfortunately it doesn't show anything in Comput Engine (yup, checked the project, user logged in, etc).  Above is filtered by my project.  If it did, and I had many different services, how would I see which service is costing me money?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting...

It looks like indeed looking at https://cloud.google.com/vpc/pricing#serverless-vpc-pricing
serverless VPC connectors could be billed as `e2-micro`
[image]

---

While in many cases you will see billing report actually try to associate your billing to human understandable service like so (under service and/or SKU columns)
[image]
it doesn't seem to be always the case.

---

One way to try to resolve that I guess would be to follow this path

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/cost-management/use-labels-to-gain-visibility-into-gcp-resource-usage-and-spending

Following instructions and once you get your billing exported to big query you could run the following:

```
select
sku.id,
l.key

from
YOUR_PROJECT.YOUR_BILLING_EXPORT_DATASET.YOUR_BILLING_TABLE
,UNNEST(labels) as l

where
 sku.id = '9FE0-8F60-A9FO' # your SKU id in question
```

and labels should give you a better idea of whats what.

---

This should give you an overall direction, perhaps there is a way to parse this out without exporting to BQ (first) and querying it (second) as this may also cost you money.

---

PS.
Labels are always a good idea when you create services/resources explicitly.

Comment: ah, thank you.  I tried to add a label to the sql instance but there is no option in gcloud console and I couldn't work out how to do that with the VPC connector (although I did discover in the labels list in billing there is a serverless VPC item).  I do feel there should be an easier way, it seems very complicated and not well designed, but perhaps there isn't an easy way.

Comment: yeah... cloud is beta i MANY cases : ) So its not necessary that you will always be able to label everything explicitly. For example, sometimes when you spin something up (say serverless VPC access) it will create sub things needed for it automatically and you wont be able to label those explicitly, but will have to hope google does so, as should be the case with VPC connectors per my understanding. Would be interesting to see if you go this route if you are actually able to pinpoint that SKU to proper label

Comment: It is probably quite complicated under the hood with so many little services packaged up into a product but yup, I'd hope it would have been easier.  In hindsight the VPC serverless connector, with the automatically configured label, was actually fairly easy to locate but sql isn't.  I'll perservere for the moment!